# MarkLogic server failed to start on Windows 7

Tags: marklogic

Marklogic server 9.0.4 is unable to start.

I ran the **Start MarkLogic Server** from start option as an administrator. I'm using Windows 7. Can you please assist?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details if you expect to get any help. A good place to start is by looking at `C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Logs\ErrorLog.txt` to see if it is reporting problems (ports not available, no disk space, etc) and update the question with any useful info from the logs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did not find disk space and port errors etc..

I found 1 warning :
2018-04-02 13:44:31.545 Warning: Metering database is not configured - Temporarily disabling usage metering
2018-04-02 13:44:31.545 Info: Database Security is online with 1 forest
2018-04-02 13:44:31.561 Info: Database Schemas is online with 1 forest

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic requires escalated priviledges in order to start.  At one point this was working in the Start menu by default but with OS Upgrades it may no longer be working.

Try this: (based on Windows 10, Win7 and win server xxx are similar)

1. Start Menu

   - ... find MarkLogic Start (often simply typing "MarkLogic" will find it)
2. RIGHT CLICK (context menu) on "Start MarkLogic Server", then
3. LEFT CLICK on "Run As Administrator"

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/startstop#id_95335

> Select Start > Programs > MarkLogic Server > Start MarkLogic Server
>
> When you start MarkLogic Server from the Start menu, the Windows service configuration for MarkLogic Server is set to start automatically. Also, **if you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7**, to start the service you must right-click the Start MarkLogic Server link in the Start menu and choose Run as Administrator, then choose to allow the action.

Answer (score 0):

You should open your Services application (Start Menu -> type in 'Services') and find MarkLogic in the services list, right click it and select 'Start'.

Once that's done you should be able to navigate to http://localhost:8001 in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to MarkLogic and taking self paced training.

Thank you for your responses. Here is what i did based on the answers i got from you all.

1. I reinstalled the files along with the converters.
2. I searched for the **Marklogic folder--> Start MarkLogic Server** in the **start--> Program**s in windows 7.
3. Right click on the **Start MarkLogic Server** as an administrator.
4. Right click on the **Admin Marklogic Server**. This will open a default URL. In my case it is **http://***.0.0.1:8001/**. So i have to change it to **http://localhost:8001**. It worked.